# Add new number as last digit of floating point number

Tags: java, double

I could need a little bit help with a small problem I faced in Java.

So let's say I have a number i that I want to attach to a double val.
It needs to work the same as you type a number on a calculator.

I know how to do so with whole numbers:

```
        double val = 7;
        double i = 2;
        val = val*10;
        val += i;
```

Then var outputs 72, just as I wanted

But I just can't figure it out how to do so with decimal places.

Lets say I have **var = 2.72** and **i = 3**.
How do I make it **output 2.723?**

It needs to work with any amount of numbers after the decimal point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (2.72*10)+3 would obviously never result in 2.723, so you'd need a different set of instructions.

Comment: If you're just trying to append it at the end... convert the value to a String, concatenate it to the String, then convert it back to a double with `Double.parseDouble(value);`.

Comment: "It needs to work with any amount of numbers after the decimal point." Then you'll probably want to take a look at [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic : (No. to be appended should be integer)

```
    Double val = 2.34;
    int p = 2;
    String s = val.toString();
    s = s + p;
    System.out.println(s);  //2.342 in string
    val = Double.parseDouble(s);
    System.out.println(val);  //2.342 in double
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(val).toString()+Math.round(i));
```

output 2.723